# pheatmap clustering within group

Tags: expression, cluster-analysis, pheatmap

I want to create a heatmap which contains gene expression data with samples that are clustered within the groups. The clustering should take place WITHIN the respective group.

Right now, my code for creating the pheatmap is like following

```
pheatmap(mat,color=colorRampPalette(c("blue", "black", "yellow"))(100), 
         annotation_col=df, 
         show_rownames = F,
         cluster_cols=F, 
         cutree_rows = 1, 
         cutree_cols = 1, 
         cluster_rows = TRUE
)
```

This code enables separate groups but without clustering within the groups.

Do you have any suggestions how to cluster within the groups? I know that somehow it is possible to separate the clustering from the whole data und only use on one group. So doing it separately and at the end bringing it together.

Right now, I tried following code but it didn't work

```
clust_list <- lapply(unique(df$Group), function(group) {
  rows <- which(df$Group == group)
  pheatmap(mat[rows, ], 
           color=colorRampPalette(c("yellow", "black", "blue"))(100), 
           show_rownames = F,
           cutree_rows = 1,
           cluster_rows = TRUE,
           cluster_cols = FALSE,
           annotation_col = df[rows, , drop = FALSE])
})
```

Combine clusters into single vector
`order <- unlist(lapply(clust_list, function(clust) clust$tree_row$order))` 
Create heatmap with clustered rows within groups

```
pheatmap(mat[order, ], 
         color=colorRampPalette(c("yellow", "black", "blue"))(100), 
         show_rownames = F,
         cutree_rows = 1, 
         cluster_rows = FALSE, 
         cluster_cols = FALSE, 
         annotation_col = df[order, , drop = FALSE])
```

Best

Tim